# How to make a shortcode attribute pass into a seperate loop using get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to get a shortcode to execute and pass the attribute value into a separate loop using get_template_part, the shortcode code is like this:

```
function test( $atts, $content = null ) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array('category' => '', 'type' => '' ), $atts ) );
    ob_start();  
    get_template_part('loop', $type);  
    $ret = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $ret; 
}
add_shortcode('test', 'test');
```

And then in the loop-$type.php file I have

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID($category);
$args=array(
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                     <li> /* post stuff */         </li>

    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
```

But I can't get the cat_id to use the $category from the shortcode attribute. Does anyone know why the loop isn't using the shortcode attribute?

It clearly isn't passing the value on, which means I could make it global, but that is a nasty solution, there must be a clean way to do it?

(I have a post that is trying to execute the shortcode as `[test category=random-category-name]`)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$category` is only within the scope of the function and isn't being passed to `get_template_part()`.
Try making `$category` global.

```
function test( $atts, $content = null ) {
  global $category;
  extract( shortcode_atts( array('category' => '' ), $atts ) );
  ob_start();
  get_template_part('loop', $type);  
  $ret = ob_get_contents();  
  ob_end_clean();  
  return $ret; 
}
add_shortcode('test', 'test');
```

Also, add `global $category;` to the top of your template file.

Comment: thanks Mitchell, but isn't setting a variable like this global bad practise? the page that loads the shortcode will run about 3-5 shortcodes that pass different category information and different loops, which makes me want to avoid global variables, don't you agree?

Comment: I do agree, but because the way you have things put together there's no way to avoid it.
Maybe look into using an alternative to the shortcode, it's an incredibly limited feature.

Comment: Ah I see, the only reason i've used shortcode is so people who use my website can easily run multiple loops on any page that load the latest posts of different categories. Do you know of any other ways I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had trouble finding a good answer.

Apparently, setting a variable global like that is not the only solution. Instead, you could just 'include' the template into the php after the variables have been set and it works just as intended.

Check here for a better description and an example:

http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/